# Reliably rotating any string

Tags: php, unicode, multibyte, multibyte-functions

I was experimenting with multibyte strings and how to handle them. Using the code that you can see here

https://gist.github.com/charlydagos/89f67808e01f97e6de91

I was successful in rotating most strings. However I noticed that the line

`$chr = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);`

Will not work for [flag emojis](https://esham.io/2015/04/emoji-flags-redux), since they use more than a single unicode code point.

You can try the following in your own shells:

This gives desired output: `$ php string_rotate_mb.php "你好"`

This however `$ php string_rotate_mb.php ""` returns `[H][C]`

Which is technically correct, it did rotate the string. But really it's single glyph and my desired output is the flag alone (or a sequence of flags, which then becomes even more garbled glyphs, sometimes even turning it into different flags).

How can I, then, reliably determine that I should grab a `$length = 1` or a `$length = 2` (or a `$length = N`) substring using `mb_substr`?

For reference, I'm using `PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2016 10:40:26) ( NTS )`, `ZSH_VERSION = 5.2`, `LC_ALL=en_us.utf-8`, and `iTerm2: Build 2.9.git.8dff8db518`.

#### Update - Feb 5th 2016

Solution: https://gist.github.com/charlydagos/6755ad994da07a7b4959#file-string_rotate_working-php-L39-L56

Thank you [roeland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4447998/roeland) for introducing the concept of Grapheme Clusters. Good info also in the following links

- http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html
- http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/06/treat-unicode-strings-as-grapheme-clusters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot more examples where this fails:

- Composing characters: compare **ê** and **ê** (the first one is actually U+0302 and U+0065)
- Variants: eg. emoji can have a black/white or color variant ︎ vs ️. This is done by adding a *variant selector* after the emoji. similar problem with ethnic variations:     . (note: support for this is a bit spotty, but at least Windows 10 supports these variants)
- Flags, which consist of two code points.
- Fractions using the Fraction dash (U+2044) may be rendered with one glyph as well. Eg. **1⁄2**. Note the difference with **1/2**

And so on…

I think what you're looking for is called grapheme clusters. Without library support I think this is pretty difficult to get right.

For recent PHP versions there is the `intl` extension. You may loop over the clusters using [the grapheme functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php).